# How do i make my picture and paragraph in the middle of my page screen

Tags: html, css

My problem is the picture and the paragraph is not in the center of the page screen it goes to the bottom instead. Can anyone help me with this?

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/YMCLJ/1/

```
<p class="center">Must be center in the screen</p>
<img class="center" src="http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/hello_zpsc60ffbf3.gif"/>
```

css

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
```

Comment: So the text and image should be centered horizontally and vertically and the image on top of the text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to have elements in absolute middle, try this simpler method:

HTML:

```
<div class="centered-container">
    <div class="centered-elements">
        <p>Must be center in the screen</p>
        <img src="http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/hello_zpsc60ffbf3.gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
centered-container {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.centered-elements{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMCLJ/13/

Comment: The paragraph is not in the centre of the screen as requested by the OP.

Comment: I don't think he wanted the text to overlap the image, or the image to overlap the text. It doesn't make any sense as he could have just use the image as background and have the text centered... -_-

Answer (score 0):

This should centre the element for you regardless of its size:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGq5V/

**UPDATE:**

It gets rather more complicated to centre an element that has no explicit dimensions. In your case, you should wrap the elements you wish to centre in a parent `<div>`:

```
<div class="center">
    <img src="http://i38.photobucket.com/albums/e149/eloginko/hello_zpsc60ffbf3.gif" />
</div>
<div class="center">
    <p>Must be center in the screen</p>
</div>
```

...so we can centre the children within using a 'ghost' element to hold it open:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
 .center:before {
    content:'oooh, a ghost';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:1px; overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-1000px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
/* center the child */
 .center > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XGq5V/1/

---

Some more discussion on the various techniques can be read at http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: The paragraph isn't centered.

Comment: Doh! That threw a spanner in the works ;) See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a negative top and left margin to 1/2 the image height/width.

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-150px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

## [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMCLJ/3/)

Comment: Doesn't help with centring the `</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [absolute centering technique](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/).

There are many ways to do it, and they all have their advantages and disadvantages, but this is the easiest:

```
.center{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/YMCLJ/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
img.center {
position: absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin:auto;
}
p.center{
text-align:center;
margin-top:50px; // change it according to your need
}
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UTn2N/

If you will put both image and paragraph inside a div then it will be easy to place them in center.